# rdflib in python tools for Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, rdflib, ptvs

I want to use rdflib in python tools for Visual Studio. I installed both python tools and rdflib.
When I write `import rdflib` in my project (in a file ***.py) and launch it, it returns an error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'value'

and points to the line `import rdflib`
Although I can open Tools->Python Tools->Execute Project in Python Interactive , and execute `import rdflib` there with no errors. But when I close that window, I still can't use the library to code in ***.py file.

How can I use rdflib from Visual Studio, how can I avoid that error?

Comment: Which PTVS and Python versions are you using?
If it is PTVS 1.5, can you try 2.0 beta? https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/103101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if you launch the program with Ctrl+F5 (instead of F5) it will work. Maybe python tools or rdflib have some problems with debugging in Visual Studio.